# CFStringRef to NSString ARC leaking. Why?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

I have been looking around for the correct way to go from `CFStringRef` to `NSString` in ARC to avoid memory leaks and some of the main voted answers suggest:

```
NSString * string = (__bridge NSString *)cfString;
```

I am using that approach here but when profiling the app I still get a memory leak in this small method [see attached image].

So, I am not sure how to fix this. Anybody has the solution to this problem?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

So, apparently adding the `CFRelease(ext)` before the return fixed the leak. Problem is I don't think I fully understand the reason. I thought that the line:

```
NSString * extension = (__bridge NSString*)ext
```

Would take ownership of the Core Foundation ext string and handle the release. 
Can anybody explain what is going on here exactly?

Comment: Oh, and it's spelled "exten ***S*** ion"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the de-facto "standard" Cocoa naming convention, functions that contain `Create` or `Copy` in their name return an object with a reference count of 1. You have to transfer this reference count into ARC-land so that ARC can take care of it. You use the `__bridge_transfer` keyword for this purpose.

```
NSString *string = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)cfString;
```

Comment: On a side note, I ask again: ARC was supposed to make memory management easier. But honestly, why `__bridge_transfer` is better than `[string release]`? We **still** have to worry about reference counts, but at least now it's **ugly.**

Comment: There might be a time in the near future you will not have to worry about bridge transfers.

Comment: You do bridges only when dancing on the edge of ARC, so you do much less bridges than you did releases on MRC.

Comment: The standard Cocoa naming conventions don't include a special meaning for names containing "Create". You are talking about the Core Foundation rule. And that's the reason ARC does not work automatically here: ARC is only defined for Cocoa objects.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Incorrect. Core Foundation is part of Cocoa. What you are talking about is that ARC only works with Objective-C objects. It's not a matter of framework, but a matter of language.

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking but I think most people (and Apple) consider Cocoa to only refer to the Objective-C frameworks (Foundation/AppKit). What I meant with my previous comment is that there are two distinct sets of naming conventions for Cocoa (see [Cocoa Memory Management Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)) and Core Foundation (see [The Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe That's right - of course, I am not, by any means, intending to confuse this rule with the `alloc-retain-copy-mutableCopy` rule.

Answer (score 4):

Release the `ext` object or use `__bridge_transfer`.

Let me explain this a bit in the way I understand it:

- `__bridge` – Normal casting. The retain count of casted object is partially managed by ARC and partially manually. You need to release the existing ownership on the `CF` side.
- `__bridge_transfer` – “Converts `CF` object to `NS` object.” The retain count of casted object is fully managed by ARC. Existing ownership on the `CF` side is disposed for you.

Comment: CFRelease(ext) also works. So this is also correct. I marked H2CO3 answers as correct since he came in first, but both answer are correct (according to instruments at least). Memory leak does not show up anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the timing is important ;)

Comment: `__bridge` might be better described as “just cast it with no memory-management effects”. If it was retained, it's still retained. If it wasn't retained, it's still doomed. `__bridge_transfer` doesn't “convert CF object to NS object” (where there are a CF class and an NS class that are “toll-free bridged”, any object of one class *already is* an object of the other; e.g., a CFString *is* an NSString, and vice versa), but the rest of that item is correct. `__bridge_retained` is effectively the inverse of transfer: it both casts and `CFRetain`s the object.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks, you are right, but: 1. `__bridge` is a simple cast, but it is usually immediately stored in `__strong` variable (or passed as argument), so it gets immediately retained by ARC. 2. I added quotation marks to the part saying “converts …”. I know about the toll-free bridge, but semanticaly it is different type with different methods and behavior.

Comment: @iMartin: 1. Technically true, but these are two separate things. The retention due to being stored into a strong variable has nothing to do with the `__bridge` cast.