# Potential Memory leak abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople( )

Tags: ios, xcode, addressbookui

This is function to reload my address book after saving changes, the line

```
self.addressbook=ABAddressbookCreateWithOptions()
```

and

```
self.contactAdd=ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBook)
```

are showing as the potential memory leak points.

contactAdd is of type CFAr`r`ayRef and address book is `ABAddressBookRef`

```
  -(void)reloadAddressBook
    {
    //   if(self.addressBook)
    //       CFRelease(self.addressBook);
       self.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,NULL);
        if(ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(self.addressBook))
        {

            ABAddressBookSave(self.addressBook,NULL);
        }
    //    if(self.contactAdd)
    //        CFRelease(self.contactAdd);

        self.contactAdd=ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBook);
    }
```

Comment: put your relevant code here :)

Comment: Are you releasing this object `temp` later?

Comment: Use _bridge_transfer when allocating because you are assigning to CFArray which is array of core foundation with no method to release or dealloc ther array. To land it on retain, release land of Objective C use _bridge.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra 
every CFRelease i gave shows a potentil memory leak..

Comment: Yeah because it is core foundation framework class so there are some leaks

Comment: @AshutoshMishra can i solve it?

Comment: Don't worry too much it doesn't create too much problem

Comment: @AshutoshMishra 
is there any way other than changing my CFArray to NSAttay to solve this potential memory leak??

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967515/cfstringref-to-nsstring-arc-leaking-why/17967622#17967622

Comment: @AshutoshMishra: “it is core foundation framework class so there are some leaks” is a gross oversimplification. If you get an object from CF or something CF-based, you need to clean it up. CF does not necessarily mean leaks, and accepting leaks just because CF was involved is sloppy programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use _addressbook instead of self.addressBook.

Comment: this guy is a legend !

Answer (score 2):

use another variable to assign like this

```
contactAddtemp=ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBook); 
self.contactAdd=(__bridge_retained CFArrayRef) CFBridgingRelease(contactAddtemp);
```

It worked for me in xcode 4.2 but when I checked it doesnt work in 4.6 may be cause it uses ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,NULL) instead of ABAddressBookCreate()

Comment: Why would you call CFBridgingRelease and then immediately cast that with `__bridge_retained`?

Comment: It balances out, but yes there is no real sense in doing this but it seems to get the job done in xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0):

[In Core Foundation, Create and Copy functions return an ownership reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html)

You need to balance that out by calling `CFRelease` on the returned object (the Address Book, the array of people, and anything else you're getting from such functions), or by casting it with `__bridge_transfer` (or by calling `CFBridgingRelease`):

```
self.addressBook = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(…));
```